# How to detect a specific constructor using SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using VS2013 and i try to detect a specific constructor (string constructor) using SFINAE.

I tried it using this code:

```
typedef char s8;
typedef s8 no[1];
typedef s8 yes[2];
template <typename C> static yes& checkIfHasStringConstructor(decltype (C(const string&)) *);
template <typename> static no& checkIfHasStringConstructor(...);
static const s8 s_iFromStringMethod = (sizeof(checkIfHasStringConstructor<TType>(0)) == sizeof(yes));
```

But for some reason i don't understand this always leads to "0" being the value of "s_iFromStringMethod" for this class:

```
class CHasStringConstructor
{
private:
    u32 m_uValue;

public:
    CHasStringConstructor() : m_uValue(0) {}
    CHasStringConstructor(const string& _sValue) : m_uValue(CBaseParser::parseU32(_sValue)) {}
};
```

I assume the problem is with my "decltype" line which seems to never trigger when compiling my code.

Comment: `std::is_constructible<C, const std::string&>`

Comment: `decltype(C(const string&))` shouldn't compile, you probably meant `decltype(C(std::declval<string>()))`

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions worked.